# Is there a way to dynamicly implement interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I'm working on a Minecraft mod that allows mod creation with Lua. I want the user to be able to create TileEntities with the interfaces they want. Currently I'm using a Base TE that calls functions of a registered Lua file, but this does not allow them to make inventories and peripherals.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for. It might be that a reflection [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) would solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can load the interface through [ClassLoader.html#loadClass(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) and implement it using [Proxy#newProxyInstance(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29)

Example:

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
Class<?> desiredInterface = cl.loadClass("SomeInterface");
Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                 cl, 
                 new Class<?>[]{desiredInterface},
                 new InvocationHandler() {
                      @Override
                      Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
                        //call Lua with method name and args, return answer
                      }
                 });
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the returned Object extend another class?

Comment: Well, yes, but AFAIK not without bytecode manipulation. Have a look at http://cglib.sourceforge.net/, http://asm.ow2.org/, http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel//index.html.